# How to use Flink Temporal Tables?

Tags: apache-flink

The new Temporal Tables in Flink look awesome but I have not yet been able to make them work. As I cannot find any working examples I wonder if anyone else has got it to work and can point out what I'm doing wrong.

Here's a little bit of context:

query:

```
SELECT s.id FROM sitemembership AS m, LATERAL TABLE (site(m.ts)) AS s WHERE m.siteId = s.id
```

The setup:

```
// { "streamName": "sitemembership", "key": "siteId" }
Table table = tableEnv.fromDataStream(stream, String.join(",", rowTypeInfo.getFieldNames()) + ",ts.rowtime");
table.printSchema();
tableEnv.registerTable(streamName, table);

// { "streamName": "site", "key": "id" }
Table table = tableEnv.fromDataStream(stream, String.join(",", rowTypeInfo.getFieldNames()) + ",ts.rowtime");
TemporalTableFunction temporalTable = table.createTemporalTableFunction("ts", key);
tableEnv.registerFunction(streamName, temporalTable);
```

I'm getting no rows whatsoever and no errors. I've tried flipping the query by changing which table I register as temporal but with no success. I have also looked at the "ts" column and get dates that makes me believe I should get at least a few rows.

Any help is appreciated.

P.S. I'm running this on historical data from kafka partitioned on "id" which is also the row key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find fully working code "examples" in form of the tests [here](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/release-1.7.1/flink-libraries/flink-table/src/test/scala/org/apache/flink/table/runtime/stream/sql/TemporalJoinITCase.scala) (Content of those two tests (processing time and event time) is more or less repeated in the documentation [here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/table/streaming/temporal_tables.html#defining-temporal-table-function) and [here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/table/streaming/temporal_tables.html) or [here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.7/dev/table/tableApi.html#joins)). You can start with those examples and then step by step convert them to your exact use case/scenario. It might be beneficial to first start with pre-defined set of data and only later switch to reading from Kafka.

Regarding your issue, it is unclear from your code snippet what is wrong, some of the potential issues:

- watermarks are not assigned/not increasing (`assignTimestampsAndWatermarks()` call in the linked `testEventTimeInnerJoin()`). Temporal Join operator emits the data only on watermark.
- row time between those two tables you are trying to join is out of sync. If `site` has no row that is old enough to be joined with `sitemembership` records, the result will be empty. Like for example if all of the records from `site` have time fields from year `2019`, while `sitemembership` have only records from `2018`.

Comment: Thank you Piotr, the test were exactly what I was looking for. Unfortunately for me I only looked at the java side. I will play around with those and I am sure I'll manage from there.